Polytopes with identical facets
Hypercubes have hypercube facets. Higher dimensional permutohedra have facets with identical facets related to hexagonal prisms (Permutohedron Facets).
Is it possible to characterize the polytopes that can serve as the facets (of unique type) of a higher dimensional convex polytope? Or at least can a polytope be defined that has identical facets that are not cubic or hexagonal prisms? Is there a 3d polytope other than a cube or hexagonal prism that can be the unique facet of a 4d polytope?

You might want to have a first look onto the regular polychora - the counterparts of 4D space to the regular polyhedra of 3D space (or the regular polygons of 2D space).

The regular pentachoron is built from 5 (= penta) identical regular tetrahedra. It somehow is the 4D equivalent of the tetrahedron. This simplex series goes on forever through all higher dimensions.
The regular octachoron (aka tesseract) is built from 8 (= octa) identical regular cubes. It somehow is the 4D equivalent of the cube (= hexahedron). This hypercubical series goes on forever through all higher dimensions.
The regular hexadecachoron is built from 16 (= hexadeca) identical tetrahedra. It somehow is the the 4D equivalent of the octahedron. This orthoplex series goes on forever through all higher dimensions.
The regular icositetrachoron is built from 24 (= icositetra) identical regular octahedra. It neither has a 3D equivalent nor within any higher dimensions.
The regular hecatonicosachoron is built from 120 (= hecatonicosa) identical dodecahedra. It somehow is the 4D equivalent of the dodecahedron. This tiny series (including the regular pentagon) stops here, no member is possible beyond dimension 4, which sticks to spherical geometry.
The regular hexacosachoron is built from 600 (= hexacosa) identical regular tetrahedra. It somehow is the 4D equivalent of the icosahedron. This tiny series stops here, no member is possible beyond dimension 4, which sticks to spherical geometry.

There are plenty other polychora outside those regular ones, just as for the 3D space too, even when restricting to symmetry equivalent vertices only and having only a single edge lengths throughout. Here we not only would have the uniform polychora, but also the scaliform polychora. For instance the bi-icositetradiminished hexacosachoron is a member of the latter class and is built from 48 tridiminished icosahedra only. In fact, it not only has a single vertex class but also just a single class of boundary elements. As such it is a noble polytope.
--- rk

Fascinating, thanks. I guess I would like to know if it is possible to determine whether, for a given uniform (or more broadly, scaliform) polyhedron, there is a (convex) polychoron that can be constructed with this polyhedron as the only cell or facet type.

There is a subset of uniform polytopes, called Wythoffian polytopes, which bows to kaleidoscopical construction. This very construction can be encoded into Coxeter-Dynkin diagrams as decorated graphs. On the other hand these undecorated graphs simply represent the Coxeter group of reflectional symmetry.

Thus starting from the CD diagram of an nD Wythoffian polytope it is known which (n+1)D symmetry groups would contain this one, i.e. all dimensional usages could be derived as graphical extensions. Then those possible extensions would have to be checked about all their other facets, which can be done from that graph directly. If those all would be the same as the started one, you would have retrieved such an according (n+1)D polytope.
